# Send data and files to Forge API using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post, autodesk-forge

I am trying to send data that identifies the photoscene ID and a dictionary of locally stored files to the Autodesk Recap API. If I send only the data, the response includes the correct photoscene ID. If I include files (using the read binary option), the request does not post any data and the API cannot identify the photoscene. I have successfully created a photoscene with Python requests and uploaded the images with curl, but would prefer to do all of this in a single Python function.

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
data = {
    'photosceneid': photoscene_id,
    'type': 'image'
}
files = {}
img_dir = os.listdir('Recap/')
for img in img_dir:
    files['file[{}]'.format(img_dir.index(img))] = open('Recap/' + img, 'rb')
post = requests.post(url='https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file', headers=headers, data=data,
                     files=files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests adds 'multipart/form-data' automatically if you use files, it also sets the 'boundary' if you set 'multipart/form-data' manually you must also set the 'boundary' so leave it to requests:

```
import requests
import os
import json

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format("xxx")
}
data = {
    'photosceneid': "xxx",
    'type': 'image'
}
files = {}
img_dir = os.listdir('Recap/')
for img in img_dir:
    files['file[{}]'.format(img_dir.index(img))] = open('Recap/' + img, 'rb')
post = requests.post(url='http://httpbin.org/post', headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
print(json.dumps(post.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Note the output has boundary set:

```
...
{
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxx",
    "Content-Length": "78299",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=cd2f6bf5f67653c6e2c423a2d23c929a",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
}
...
```

If you set 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' manually, boundary is not set:

```
...
{
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxx",
    "Content-Length": "78299",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
}
...
```